# How to append values to the list in shell script..?

Tags: bash, scripts

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /pg
file=`ls -l |awk '{print $9}'`
list=()
for i in $a
do
   echo $i
   a=`cat /pg/$i | head  -n  1 |awk '{print $8}' ` #output: first interation 15 & 2nd values 60
   list+=($a)
   
   #a1=`cat /pg/$i | head -n 2 |awk '{print $8}'`
done
echo $list
```

through this `` a=`ls -l |awk '{print $9}'` ``  I'm getting two file and iterating through for loop
and appending values to list() the list should contains "15","16" but list contains only one value is "15"
Please  help me to fix the same.

Comment: Re-defining `$a` in the loop will not alter what `for` is iterating over: demo: `a="1 2 3 4 5"; for i in $a; do a="6 7 8 9"; echo $i; done`. If that is not your intention, pick a different variable name: using "a" for 2 different purposes is confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access the whole array, use

```
echo "${list[@]}"
```

Using just `$list` is equivalent to `${list[0]}`, i.e. it only shows the first element.

Answer (score 3):

```
# create list
hosts1=()
hosts2=()
# add hosts
hosts1+=( host1 )
hosts1+=( host2 )
hosts2+=( host3 )
hosts2+=( host4 )
# combine 2 lists
hosts1+=( ${hosts2[@]} )
# add some more
echo ${hosts1[@]}
hosts1+=( host5 )
hosts1+=( host6 )
echo ${hosts1[@]}
```